# Unfold/simp has no effect in a primrec type class instantiation proof

Tags: isabelle

Up until several days ago, I always defined a type, and then proved theorems directly about the type. Now I'm trying to use type classes.

**Problem**

The problem is that I can't instantiate `cNAT` for my type `myD` below, and it appears it's because `simp` has no effect on the abstract function `cNAT`, which I've made concrete with my `primrec` function `cNAT_myD`. I can only guess what's happening because of the automation that happens after `instance proof`.

**Questions**

**Q1:** Below, at the statement `instantiation myD :: (type) cNAT`, can you tell me how to finish the proof, and why I can prove the following theorem, but not the type class proof, which requires `injective`?

```
theorem dNAT_1_to_1: "(dNAT n = dNAT m) ==> n = m"

assumes injective: "(cNAT n = cNAT m) ==> n = m"
```

**Q2:** This is not as important, but at the bottom is this statement:

```
instantiation myD :: (type) cNAT2
```

It involves another way I was trying to instantiate `cNAT`. Can you tell me why I get `Failed to refine any pending goal` at `shows`? I put some comments in the source to explain some of what I did to set it up. I used this slightly modified formula for the requirement `injective`:

```
assumes injective: "!!n m. (cNAT2 n = cNAT2 m) --> n = m"
```

### Specifics

My contrived `datatype` is this, which may be useful to me someday: *(Update: Well, for another example maybe. A good mental exercise is for me to try and figure out how I can actually get something inside a `'a myD list`, other than `[]`. With `BNF`, something like `datatype_new 'a myD = myS "'a myD fset"` gives me the warning that there's an unused type variable on the right-hand side)*

```
datatype 'a myD = myL "'a myD list"
```

The type class is this, which requires an injective function from `nat` to `'a`:

```
class cNAT =
  fixes cNAT :: "nat => 'a"
  assumes injective: "(cNAT n = cNAT m) ==> n = m"
```

### dNAT: this non-type class version of cNAT works

```
fun get_myL :: "'a myD => 'a myD list" where
  "get_myL (myL L) = L"

primrec dNAT :: "nat => 'a myD" where
  "dNAT 0       = myL []"
 |"dNAT (Suc n) = myL (myL [] # get_myL(dNAT n))"

fun myD2nat :: "'a myD => nat" where
  "myD2nat (myL [])       = 0"
 |"myD2nat (myL (x # xs)) = Suc(myD2nat (myL xs))"

theorem left_inverse_1 [simp]:
  "myD2nat(dNAT n) = n"
apply(induct n, auto)
by(metis get_myL.cases get_myL.simps)

theorem dNAT_1_to_1:
  "(dNAT n = dNAT m) ==> n = m"
apply(induct n)
apply(simp) (*
  The simp method expanded dNAT.*)
apply(metis left_inverse_1 myD2nat.simps(1))
by (metis left_inverse_1)
```

### cNAT: type class version that I can't instantiate

```
instantiation myD :: (type) cNAT
begin
primrec cNAT_myD :: "nat => 'a myD" where
  "cNAT_myD 0       = myL []"
 |"cNAT_myD (Suc n) = myL (myL [] # get_myL(cNAT_myD n))"

instance
proof 
  fix n m :: nat
show "cNAT n = cNAT m ==> n = m"
  apply(induct n)
  apply(simp) (*
The simp method won't expand cNAT to cNAT_myD's definition.*)
  by(metis injective)+ (*
Metis proved it without unfolding cNAT_myD. It's useless. Goals always remain,
and the type variables in the output panel are all weird.*)
oops
end
```

### cNAT2: Failed to refine any pending goal at `show`

```
(*I define a variation of `injective` in which the `assumes` definition, the
  goal, and the `show` statement are exactly the same, and that strange `fails
  to refine any pending goal shows up.*)
class cNAT2 =
  fixes cNAT2 :: "nat => 'a"
  assumes injective: "!!n m. (cNAT2 n = cNAT2 m) --> n = m"

instantiation myD :: (type) cNAT2
begin
primrec cNAT2_myD :: "nat => 'a myD" where
  "cNAT2_myD 0       = myL []"
 |"cNAT2_myD (Suc n) = myL (myL [] # get_myL(cNAT2_myD n))"
instance
proof (*
  goal: !!n m. cNAT2 n = cNAT2 m --> n = m.*)
show 
  "!!n m. cNAT2 n = cNAT2 m --> n = m"

  (*Failed to refine any pending goal 
    Local statement fails to refine any pending goal
    Failed attempt to solve goal by exported rule:
      cNAT2 (n::nat) = cNAT2 (m::nat) --> n = m *)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function `cNAT` is polymorphic in its result type, but the type variable does not appear among the parameters. This often causes type inference to compute a type which is more general than you want. In your case for `cNAT`, Isabelle infers for the two occurrences of `cNAT` in the `show` statement the type `nat => 'b` for some `'b` of sort `cNAT`, but their type in the goal is `nat => 'a myD`. You can see this in jEdit by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-hovering over the `cNAT` occurrences to inspect the types. In ProofGeneral, you can enable printing of types with `using [[show_consts]]`.

Therefore, you have to explicitly constrain types in the `show` statement as follows:

```
fix n m
assume "(cNAT n :: 'a myD) = cNAT m"
then show "n = m"
```

Note that it is usually not a good idea to use Isabelle's meta-connectives `!!` and `==>` inside a `show` statement, you better rephrase them using `fix`/`assume`/`show`.

Comment: Andreas, thanks again. I always have `show_consts` on, but with type variables, I didn't understand what I was looking at. Vars `'a` and `'b` were pretty much the same to me. I've read M.Wenzel say that type classes are a first-order logic, so this helps make more sense of that. This also helps me get closer to having a complete awareness of effects that occur due to type inference and polymorphism, in particular as to their relationship to that `Failed to refine any pending goal` error. Now that I've understood two different causes for it, it's making more sense. Thanks for the !!/==> tip.